# Can't import arcpy in IDLE, pyscripter, or even ArcGIS10.1's Python window

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, installation

After using arcpy and python for months with ArcGIS 10.1 without any problems I'm encountering something I can't work around or even find help with online.  Something as simple as "import arcpy" is failing for no reason I can think of:

```
>>> import arcpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from arcpy.toolbox import *
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\toolbox.py", line 342, in <module>
    from management import Graph, GraphTemplate
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 153
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py on line 154, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

I've looked around and I've seen other people with similar symptomes but nothing with the same last message, the `Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py on line 154, but no encoding declared;` part seems different.

I haven't done anything like installing new python extensions or versions or any other type of software.  The only thing remotely related was that I had an FME process working in the background while I was testing my code.  I didn't modify any pre-existing ArcGIS python scripts.

I have tried using IDLE installed by ArcGIS 10.1, pyscripter, and the Python window that can be opened inside of ArcGIS.  I tried rebooting on the off chance it was some fluke.  The only thing I can think of to try next is a fresh instal, and if that doesn't work maybe going as extreme as wiping the PC's OS and starting over from scratch.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you might have some file system corruption going on. I would back up your important work and then check your file system for errors. Off topic for this site of course so hit up Google.

Comment: Just sounds like a bad installation to me. You may need to reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

For me a basic uninstall/reinstall of ArcGIS 10.1 is relatively painless taking perhaps 30 mins in total, so as @JasonScheirer says I would try that for a possible quick fix - but take care if your install has lots installed on top of it.

If you have not read the bottom of this **[page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z00000008000000)** from the Online Help about **Paths and Import** it may be worth doing so (although it may not be related to this specific problem).